# Paint to screen with go-cairo

Tags: go, cairo

I'm using http://github.com/ungerik/go-cairo as a cairo library to paint to the screen. I'm completely unfamiliar with this library and cairo in general; however, I've been scouring over documentation for both this library and various cairo bindings for other languages hoping to understand how to paint to screen (unfortunately, I haven't been able to find many tutorials for painting to the screen--only for saving images as .PNGs).

This is what I have so far, and it's not producing any effect (nothing displays). Any help would be appreciated.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/ungerik/go-cairo"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    surface := cairo.NewSurface (cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 240, 80)
    surface.SelectFontFace ("serif", cairo.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,
        cairo.FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD)
    surface.SetFontSize(32.0)
    surface.SetSourceRGB(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    surface.MoveTo (10.0, 50.0)
    surface.ShowText ("Hello World")

    for {
        surface.Paint ()
        time.Sleep (1000)
    }
    //surface.Finish()
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @zneak Sorry, that was stupid of me, I updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Linux
here's an example https://github.com/Joker/go-cairo/blob/master/example/xcb_joy.go
you have to use a go-cairo fork https://github.com/Joker/go-cairo
and XCB must be installed